# How can I share a saved search for Console.app?

Tags: command-line, console

I'm using Console.app to debug an iPhone app that my team is building. I've customized my view of the events in Console by filtering to exclude noisy libraries, subsystems, and messages.

While I can copy and paste from the search bar inside Console.app and back into the same, I can't seem to share this filter in a way that someone else can paste it into the Console app on their machine.

When I paste the contents of the search bar, I see the following:

```
process:callserviced
message:Require cycle
library:libnetwork.dylib
library:libboringssl.dylib
library:CFNetwork
library:libusrtcp.dylib
library:AudioToolboxCore
subsystem:com.apple.UIKit
subsystem:com.apple.bluetooth
subsystem:com.apple.hangtracer
subsystem:com.apple.coreaudio
subsystem:com.apple.PlugInKit
subsystem:com.apple.UserNotifications
subsystem:com.apple.runningboard
subsystem:com.apple.corehaptics
```

There are two issues here.

1. All but the first are excluded from my search, yet they appear as though they should be included.
2. When attempting to paste this into Console's search bar, it all runs together into one line, and doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

P.S. I am also open to solutions using the Terminal. I found an old thread on `hints.macworld.com` which suggests one can use the `syslog -C` command to view these logs: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20120528025400312

Unfortunately, that seems to be replaced by the `log` command now, and I don't know where to start with that.

Comment: I'm also interested in this. Some info in case is helps anyone solve this: I found it saves data to the general pasteboard with type `com.apple.consolekit.pasteboard.filter`. The data is saved via `NSKeyedArchiver`, but looking at it I can only see the first filter, and the types used for the filter don't seem to be available in any public system headers I can think off.